# Help with context-free grammar of lots of literal text with some special syntax

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

How do you make a context free grammar that analyzes mostly literal text (spaces, characters, symbols, etc.) while also looking for expressions of the form ${...} or $someCommand{...}? Note if it finds "I got $10 today", it should not do anything special with it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Since this is the right answer, I believe you will accept it.

Comment: Sure, I think I found my problem anyway. The default for this parser is to do words and not characters, so I was having trouble parsing strings like "dsa${..}", because if it found this string, $ wouldn't be recognized. Once I disabled the automatic whitespace parsing that came out of the box, and just did 1 character at a time, it works.